# When exactly is a class loaded?

Tags: java, classloader

If I have a static variable that is assigned a value from a class that uses a singleton pattern, does that somehow require that all the classes that could potentially assign a value to that static variable to be loaded?

I am working with code that looks something like this (simplified to protect corporate data):

```
private static DEVICE_FACTORY;

String factoryType = propertyFile.getDeviceFactoryType();

if(factoryType.equals("REAL"))
   DEVICE_FACTORY = RealDeviceFactory.getInstance();
else
   DEVICE_FACTORY = SimulatedDeviceFactory.getInstance();
```

The code for each type of factory is in totally different projects.  The production version of the application jar does not contain any of the simulated classes.  My problem is that when I try to test my production code I am gettting "`NoClassDefFoundError`" caused by "`ClassNotFoundException`".  I have confirmed that the property is correctly set to "REAL" so I have no idea why the JVM is even attempting to create/load the Simulated classes...

EDIT I will try to create a simplified version that demonstrates the problem tomorrow.  The stack trace (edited to protected corporate data) is as follows:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: my/package/SimulatedDeviceFactory
                at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
                at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
                at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
                at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.package.SimulatedDeviceFactory
                at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
                at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
                at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Could it be that I am using the singleton pattern on each type of device factory therefore, even though I am not going to use the SimulatedDeviceFactory, because I am using a static method call from that class the JVM thinks it needs to load it anyway?

If that is the case I could use reflection and a FQCN to resolve that quickly enough...

Comment: Can you reduce this to an example that reproduces the problem?  The details really matter in a case like this, and your code is not valid (you can't have floating if statements in a class definition)

Comment: Does the exception get thrown in that `else` branch?

Comment: You did remember to put the jar files for the other projects in your classpath, **right**?

Comment: Post the full stack trace too.

Comment: The `NoClassDefFoundError` in the trace clearly shows that **the JVM** (not a custom class loader) is trying to load the `SimulatedDeviceFactory` class. That means either `factoryType`  is not "REAL", or something else somewhere is triggering the loading of that class.

Comment: @BheshGurung I am wondering could it be that in order to load my application class the entire IF statement has to be loaded and because I am using a static method call on the simulated class that requires the simulated class to be loaded too - even though I know that code fragment will never be executed in production.  Does this make sense?

Comment: Note that there is a significant distinction between the *loading* of a class and its *initialization*.  But as others suggest, a class is *loaded* when it is referenced for any reason, as when needed to verify another class that's being loaded.  In your case you need to use a "factory" scheme (using, eg, `Class.forName`) to create your XDeviceFactory instance so that no hard-coded reference appears in the source of other classes.

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.programcreek.com/2013/01/when-and-how-a-java-class-is-loaded-and-initialized/.
Classes are loaded when they are referenced in a class file most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

This is how Java works. SimulatedDeviceFactory is loaded while loading the main class.

You should use reflection in that situation. It is good and quite common patter. Easy to configure and easy to debug.

Avoid using any other workaround. Debuging  classloader related issues in JEE application servers is really pain in a**.